# Integral of $(x^2 \sin (x))/(x^4 + 2 x ^2 - 1)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I recently had this integral on a test $$\int ^\pi _{-\pi} \frac{x^2 \sin (x)}{x^4 -2x^2 -1} dx$$

Mr professor claims this is actually equal to zero because the function is periodic and the top is odd, whereas the bottom is even. I graphed this out and it does seem that the function is symmetric about the origin, which means it's conceivable that all the contributions to the integral will cancel themselves out, but I'm not convinced. I plugged this into Mathematica and it says the integral doesn't converge.

I've got *no* idea how to go about solving this, and seeing how nasty the mathematica solution is, I'm not expecting any of you to do that either. My question is, can we really say anything about this integral without truly solving it?

Comment: The function is not periodic

Comment: The integrand in the title is not the same as the integrand in the body of the message.  However, even if we use the integrand in the title, the same problem arises:  we get an integral of the form $\int_u^v f(x)/(x-a) dx$ with $a\in (u,v)$, $f(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: I edited it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let:

$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}sin(x)}{x^{4}-x^{2}-1}$.

Note that $f(-x)=\frac{-x^{2}sinx}{x^{4}-x^{2}-1}=-f(x)$.

Hence the function is odd.

And since the function passes through the origin, and the integral between $\pi$ and $-\pi$ is the signed area bounded by the curve and $x$ axis, the total area is $0$.

Comment: So an odd integrand always guarantees an even function will come out of the integral?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true, but I was referring to the symmetry about the origin. Sketching the curve will reveal that integral between 0 and $\pi$ is the negative of the integral between $-\pi$ and 0. This is true of any odd function that passes through the origin.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I wasn't sure if the area was equal to infinity. I mean, it's not true that $ \infty - \infty = 0$, right? As far as I know, you can't really tell if the area is infinity by looking at its graph.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is $0$ at $x=\pm  g$ where $g=\sqrt {(1+\sqrt 5)/2}$ ...(both of which lie in $(-\pi,\pi)$)... and at no other real $x$. The numerator is not $0$ at $x=\pm g.$ In a small nbhd of $ g$ the integrand behaves like $k/(x-g)$ with constant $k\ne 0$ so $\int_0^{\pi}f(x) dx$ does NOT exist. However if we let $A=\lim_{e\to 0+}(\int_0^{g-e}+\int_{g+e}^{\pi})f(x) dx$ and $B=\lim_{e\to 0^+}(\int_{-\pi}^{-g-e}+\int_{-g+e}^0)f(x) dx$ then $A$ and $B$ do exist. And $A+B=0$ because $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for $x\ne \pm g$. But this is not the  def'n of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) dx.$

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you're getting at. You say the integral with limits $[0, \pi]$ doesn't exist, but then you say it does exist if you define it differently. Your last sentence confuses me as well. If what you've shown isn't the definition of $\int ^\pi _{-\pi}$ what was the point of the rest of your answer?

Comment: It does not exist as stated. The rest was a digression.

Comment: So my professor was wrong? If I'm gonna bring it up with him, I want to make sure I'm not wrong.

Comment: Just ask him what happens in a nbhd of $x=\sqrt {(1+\sqrt 5)/2}$.